# javafx get exactly display text of cell in tableview

Tags: tableview, javafx

this seem a simple question but I can get only the real value of cell, not the display text because I use tableColumn.setCellFactory to change the display text of cell (use a method to convert from real value to my disired text), so the cell will have 2 values: display text and real value. I can re-convert but it's a silly solution :(

```
cell = t.getColumns().get(col).getCellData(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the renderer directly. Among the reasons is that you'd have to access the VirtualFlow that contains the display nodes. However, I give you an answer to the detail information you posted:

> In order to make an agnostic export functionality (to CSV, XLS etc.)
>   it would be very convenient to request cell text, rather than data,
>   from a table view. Is that possible?

For any kind of export use a converter.

You never know what target format your users have. Your users could have different number format settings in your JavaFX application than what they have in Excel. Using Excel you need to get your JavaFX model data and set Excel's model data. Don't export using the view data and expect importing in Excel view would work, you'll run into problems.

Same for CSV. If you are e. g. on german localization, a 2 decimals number will look like 123,45 in your table instead of 123.45. So when you export the table's view data, you'll break your CSV format.

You won't get around exporting your model data via a proper converter.

Comment: Do you mean a converter to convert the bare model class directly to the output format? Anyway, I was thinking more of internal structures (Say, `Person` class for example) which are rendered as a string to the TableView, and I don't (maybe can't) have a `toString` for, but naturally I don't want the entire lookup mechanism (this Person ID has this name etc.) reside inside my CSV file.

Comment: Yes, a converter for the list that represents the model of the table.

Comment: But that means I have to make an implementation for every such table. I have dozens of them, and would really much prefer having a generic way of exporting the data. Having one which does the same thing the `TableView` does is good enough.

Comment: For a generic solution you can check out my tableview [copy/paste](https://gist.github.com/Roland09/6fb31781a64d9cb62179) demo. Or you could implement a converter interface for your classes in the model. Or you could implement custom exportable properties which are subclasses from the standard properties. Several solutions come to mind. But in either case, if you want a stable and flexible application, you'll need a converter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getItems() method to access the model of the Table. Based on the row id you can get the DataModel for that row.

```
tblSampleTable.getItems().get(rowId);
```

So you have a reference to the DataModel, that means you can access all the data (actual data)

Comment: No, I do not want to get the actual data, I want to get the display data

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the display text of TableView you can do this:

```
public void showAllText(TableView<?> tv){
     for (Node r: tv.lookupAll(".table-row-cell")) {
          for (Node c: r.lookupAll(".table-cell")) {
              TableCell<?, ?> tc=(TableCell<?, ?>) c;
              System.out.print(tc.getText()+" \t ");                                      
          }
          System.out.println("");
     }
```

}

Good luck.

Comment: beware: that'll work only for cells/rows that are visible in the viewport - those off don't exist!